# Dyndns doesn't resolve ip when requested from the ip in question

Tags: networking, dyndns

I have setup dyndns to point to a home server,   My ip resovles from dyndns just fine from any ip except when I'm at home.

So basically I cannot access my dyndns urls at home. I can access the server in question using a local ip, but would rather solve whatever issue is causing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's the resolving that fails, or is it the actual connection? Some router configurations don't allow for connecting to the external IP address from the inside network (called NAT reflection).

Comment: You are correct, however when I use my ip directly to connect to my home server, is works fine.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/166256/why-i-cannot-conect-to-nated-host/166495#166495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your NAT box does not do NAT reflection, I call these br0ken.

If your NAT setup does not change the port, you can use the `hosts` file to point the dyndns address to your internal ip on your home PC.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved to problem by overriding the A RR for my DynDNS domain name in my local DNS. If you are not running a DNS server in your LAN, you might consider telling the router's DNS server to do so, if it has a configurable DNS server.